# MySQL Autoupdate Timestamp and trigger execution order

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any documentation (couldn't fine in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html) that specifies whether an automatic update on `Timestamp` column or trigger executes first?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
    `id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    update_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
    `id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    update_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

delimiter $$
DROP TRIGGER if EXISTS `trigger_upd_table1` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_upd_table1` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES (new.`id`, new.`update_time`);
END $$
delimiter ;


INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`) VALUES ('100');


UPDATE `table1` t1
SET t1.id = '101'
WHERE t1.id = '100';
```

To further clarify with an example. When I run the update query for the single record in `table1`, will the automatic update on `update_time` column execute first or the trigger that is specified on `table1`. Currently, I am testing in v8.0.15 and seeing that automatic update on `update_time` column takes place first. Then the updated record is inserted into `table2`.

But is there any documentation that specifies the behavior?

Comment: The trigger is defined as `AFTER` update, so the update will complete (including the update of `update_time`) first.

Comment: This is about the closest specification of behaviour from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html): "trigger_time is the trigger action time. It can be BEFORE or AFTER to indicate that the trigger activates before or after each row to be modified."